# Inserting string with commas sqlplus

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sqlplus

I'm unable to get a string into my table that has commas, is my datatype incorrect? I've been battling this and can't find an answer anywhere online lol.
I get a too many values error- "ORA-00913: too many values"

```
create table customer (cust_id number(5) not null primary key,
cust_name char(25),
year_born number(4));

insert into customer values(1,  ‘Harry, L’, 2002);
insert into customer values(2, ‘Sally, P’, 1992);
insert into customer values(3, ‘Lio, L’ ,1998);
insert into customer values(4, ‘Patel, P’, 2001);
insert into customer values(5, ‘Roner, K’, 1978);
insert into customer values(6, ‘Jackson, O’, 2002);
insert into customer values(7, ‘Long, P’, 2001);
insert into customer values(8, ‘Smith, G’, 1992);
insert into customer values(9, ‘Harry, L’, 2002);
insert into customer values(10, ‘Paner, K’, 1978);
insert into customer values(11, ‘Dan, U’, 2010);
insert into customer values(12, ‘Patel, M’, 2001);
```

Comment: Use straight single quotes, e.g. `'Harry, L'`.

Comment: **Why haven't you posted the error code?** `ORA-error` codes are meant for a reason.

Comment: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: If you picked that code from an on-line tutorial, you'd better find a more reliable source (I understand you are not using Microsoft Word as text editor for programming).

Comment: I wrote the code, I'm in a DBA class with a crappy teacher, i can;t seem to get past this error. Syntax is incorrect or im using the wrong data type when I set up my table, I'm not sure

Comment: No, you're using the wrong quotes, as jarlh said a while ago. Mmm, except, that would give ORA-00911: invalid character, not ORA-00913. Did you copy and paste your code into the question?

Comment: WOW, so yeah my comp was using curly quotes, went and changed them to straight quotes and it all goes in fine now, thanks @jarlh

Comment: Computers don't use quotes. It must be your text editor and decent text editors would never do that. Which one are you using if I may ask?

Comment: I meant in my keyboard settings, it was set to use curly quotes, i set it to straight quotes. Im using textedit (mac)

Comment: Probably not a good choice: "TextEdit is a simple, open source **word processor** and text editor" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit)

Comment: Any recommendations for a good text editor?

Comment: Just make sure it's a text editor and not a word processor ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off "smart-quotes" in whatever your editor is.  Oracle does not see them as proper single quotes and is trying to insert them as normal characters.  This means it sees the enclosed comma as a field-separating comma, not as a comma contained in the data, and thinks you are trying to insert 4 data elements instead of 3 thus causing the error.

Note this can happen when you copy/paste too.  You may have to edit the smart quotes to proper single-quotes.